# How to perform multiple js actions from one button in atk4

Tags: atk4

--EDIT: This is now SOLVED.

I want one button to do multiple js commands, e.g.

```
$nextButton = $form->addButton('Next');
```

to do:

```
$button_repopulate_address->js(true)->show()
$street->js(true)->closest('fieldset')->show()
```

when:

```
$nextButton->isClicked()
```

The example code [here](http://demo.atk4.com/demo.html?t=6) suggests that you nest the commands in the 2nd paramater of the js call like this:

```
$g->addButton('Show all buttons')->js('click',$b1->js(null,$b2->js(null,$b3->js()->show())->show())->show());
```

I think this is very ugly and will create code that is very difficult to follow for more than 2 commands.

I looked in the source and found the _prepend command, which I've used to solved my problem by doing this:

```
if($nextButton->isClicked()){
      $form->js()->_prepend($street->js(true)->closest('fieldset')->show())
                 ->_prepend($button_repopulate_address->js(true)->show())
              ->execute();
}
```

EDIT: I just looked at the source of js() and it appears that you can pass an array to js which calls the _prepend method for each item in the array - nice!:

```
$form->js(null, array(
     $street->js(true)->closest('fieldset')->show(),
     $button_repopulate_address->js(true)->show()
));
```

--SOLVED (but perhaps the [example](http://demo.atk4.com/demo.html?t=6) I linked to could be updated with this much better functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained here:

http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/chains/multi

The examples will be revised very shortly, we're working on a new example site.